# Node ID can be different from Node label

Tags: r, networkd3

I'm trying to make a force network layout using the excellent `networkD3` library. The argument I pass to `NodeID` is a numeric column which is uniquely valued at each row. I want to set the label of the node to a different column than the one mapped to `NodeID`. This label column need or need not be unique across rows. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Example -
In the help entry for `forceNetwork`, you can see the example -

```
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source",
             Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
             Group = "group", opacity = 0.4, zoom = TRUE)
```

The labels in the output are mapped to the same column as NodeID. Can the labels be mapped to a different column?

Comment: How to know without an example of what you have and what you want.

Comment: I don't think an example makes a difference in this case but anyway, I'll add one.

Comment: I should have added **reproducible**.

Comment: This isn't an issue. This is most likely an enhancement. How do you suggest I make a reproducible example for a feature that isn't there?

Comment: How to know if it is possible through other package, if you don't show what you have and what you want to get?

Comment: What I have is the example code. What I want is in the lines just after - "The labels in the output are mapped to the same column as NodeID. Can the labels be mapped to a different column?" I"m unable to understand which part isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

The labels can be mapped to any column in the "links" data frame. If you look at your example, the `source` and `target` values are integers that run from 0 to N (Note that `networkD3` expects zero indexing of node IDs). The label for the nodes, however, is given by the `name` column in the "links" data frame.

```
> head(MisNodes)
             name group size
1          Myriel     1   15
2        Napoleon     1   20
3 Mlle.Baptistine     1   23
4    Mme.Magloire     1   30
5    CountessdeLo     1   11
6        Geborand     1    9
```

NOTE: the documentation states that "If no ID is specified then the nodes must be in the same order as the Source variable column in the Links data frame."